# Confusing outputs of references, how to analyse?

Tags: c++, reference

So I don't really understand what references do. My homework assignment is to give the output for the following code. But A,B,H always change from being and int to int&.

```
a) A = int, B = int, H = int
b) A = int, B = int, H = int&
c) A = int, B = int&, H = int
d) A = int&, B = int, H = int
e) A = int&, B = int, H = int&
f) A = int&, B = int&, H = int
```

```
#include<iostream>

int foo (A a, B b) 
{
  H h = a; a = b;
  b = h; return h;
}

int main() 
{
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int r = foo (a, b);
  std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << r;

  return 0; 
}
```

So, **a)** was obviously not a problem. But already b) confused me.

for **b)**; `int& h = a` is setting h's address to a's address? So `h == Adresse of a`, meaning value of `h == a`. Then `a = b` (where b == 2) which makes `a == b == h == 2`, so why is `a == 1` in the output?

for **c)**; `h == 1` is clear, but the line `a = b` I find very confusing. b is a reference, not? Does that mean, that b's address is now the same as the address of a, meaning value of `a == b`? I'm guessing my thoughts are correct, because I get the proper output.

for **d)**; `h = reference of a` so a has the same address like h? Then a has the name address as b? So `a == b == 2`. But now comes the weird part for me. `b = h` but `b == 2`, so `2 = h`, but isn't that a conflict with L/R - values? And why is h now 1?

for **e)**; no clue, int& h ?= int& a, what happens here? h and a have the same address? Then the address of a is now b? So the address is 2? Then b holds the address of h?

for **f)**; First, h has now the address of a, so `h == a`. Then a has the same address as b. Then the address of b is the same as h. Correct thinking?

Solutions are

```
a) 1 2 1
b) 1 2 2
c) 1 1 1
d) 2 2 1
e) 2 2 2
f) 2 1 1
```

I need especially help with b) and e), thanks a lot and sorry for the long text.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Comment: What type is `H`? Also `C` is not present in the snippet. `H` == `C`?

Comment: `s/C/H/g` maybe?

Comment: my bad, C should be H

Comment: I think this is a good question underneath. The problem is I'm confused. There is no `C` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

b)

> for b); int& h = a is setting h's address to a's address?

The reference is not an object, and it does not have an address. `h` refers to `a` of `foo`.

> So why is a == 1 in the output?

Because the parameter `A a` of `foo` is a separate object from `int a` of `main` function. `H h` refers to this local variable within `foo` and not the one in `main`. Assigning the local `int` within one function has no effect on a local variable of another function. `a` was initialised to 1 in `main` and that variable is not modified at all.

---

c)

> b is a reference, not?

Yes. `b` within `foo` is a reference in case c).

> Does that mean, that b's address is now the same as the address of a, meaning value of a == b?

Again, references are not objects and don't have addresses. `b` in `foo` refers to `b` in `main`.

---

d)

> h = reference of a so a has the same address like h? Then a has the name address as b?

Again, references are not objects and don't have addresses. `a` in `foo` refers to `a` in `main`.

> And why is h now 1?

Because that's what it is initialised to within `foo`.

---

e)

> no clue, int& h ?= int& a, what happens here? h and a have the same address? Then the address of a is now b? So the address is 2? Then b holds the address of h?

Again, references are not objects and don't have addresses. The reference `a` in `foo` refers to the `a` in `main` given as an argument, and `h` refers to that same object. `b` is not a reference.

---

d)

> First, h has now the address of a, so h == a. Then a has the same address as b. Then the address of b is the same as h.

`h` is not a reference. `b` in `foo` refers to the `b` in `main`, and `a` refers to `a` in `main`.

Comment: But I thought i.e. y = &x means y holds the address of x? Or does int& x mean something totally else?$

Answer (score 1):

In the case `b)`

```
b) A = int, B = int, H = int&
```

neither original `a` nor `b` is changed in the function because the function deals with copies of the variables (the variables are passed by value).

`h` is of a referenced type that references the variable `a` inside the function.

```
 H h = a;
```

So in this statement

```
a = b;
```

the value of `h` will be the value of `a` after the assignment. So `h` will be equal to `2`. And the output will be

```
b) 1 2 2
```

As for the case `e)`

```
e) A = int&, B = int, H = int&
```

then the only difference compared with the case `b)` is that the variable `a` is passed by reference. So not the only variable `h` but also the original variable `a` will be changed after this assignment

```
a = b;
```

So the output will be

```
e) 2 2 2
```